# Fail to capture neighbor's POST request under same router using nodejs

Tags: node.js, http-post

I'm writing a small Node express app. Currently writing a post method to capture those requests with a file and trying to save locally. When I tested it with my own machine (localhost:8888), everything works fine. Then I used another machine which connects to same router and posting a request with a file, I couldn't capture the file at all. Below is my code,

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    console.log(req.file);
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
}
);

var save = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/save', save.single('somefile'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    res.send();
});
```

When I test locally, I could see the file successfully uploaded to my "uploads" folder. But when I use another machine under same router, and calling this localhost by IP, although it shows status code 200, the `req.file` shows *undefined*, thus the file will not be saved to my localhost machine. What did I miss here?

Below's how I tested with Postman on both machines.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out working fine after I switch to another testing env (from my friend's home to my own house). So it shouldn't be anything wrong with coding or testing. It's more likely to be the env, I'm suspecting the router. So that this question is no more valid under given categories. I don't know how to close this question. But folks could discuss the cause of this weird behavior if interested.